# Javascript - Wait for web worker to finish?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-worker, topic-modeling

I am implementing the [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) algorithm of Topic Modelling in javascript as a part of a project. Upon the click of a button, the function to perform LDA is called. However since this is a very heavy task, the browser used to hang for around 15 seconds when the function was called (even the loading animated gif wasn't working while processing was taking place).

So I implemented the function as a [web worker](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html). This solves the hanging problem but now the loading animation disappears within a couple of seconds while the results are shown some 12-14 seconds after that.

Is there any way I can make the loader animate while the processing is going on ? I mean wait for the web worker to finish computing before the loading animation disappears.

The script is called asynchronously and the loader is attached to ajax events of jQuery as

```
$('#spinner').bind("ajaxSend", function() {
   $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: do not attach it to the ajax events.. not too familiar with web worker to tell u where to attach it, but it should have some event handlers of its own..

Comment: would love to see your LDA implementation

Comment: @editor its open source work so you can follow it here: https://github.com/ekanshpreet/data-portraits

Comment: Gracias. Anywhere I can see it in action?

Comment: @editor you can have a look at it here http://nsitonline.in/ekansh/berkman.. Its a project still in its very early stages so there might be bugs :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate the spinner before inititating the (heavy) worker logic, and disable the spinner once the worker is finished:

```
var worker = new Worker('workerscript.js');
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    // Do something with event.data, then hide the spinner.
    $('#spinner').hide();
};
$('#spinner').show();
worker.postMessage({args: ' foo bar '});
```

`workerscript.js` would look like this:

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    var results;
    // do something
    ...
    // Done:
    postMessage(results);
};
```